# Low Disk Space - The volume "Filesystem root" has only 560.3 MB disk space reamining

Tags: partitioning

Today, I tried to update my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.  About half way through downloading the new files I got the "Low Disk Space - The volume "Filesystem root" has only 560.3 MB disk space reamining" message.  I then aborted the update to 14.04.

How can I get rid of this ? Is there a simple way to remove these files I uploaded ?  I think this would be the simpliest thing to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing to do would be clear the package cache.

run this command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If that doesn't help, consider booting into a Ubuntu Live Media and [resizing](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) the root partition using Gparted.

Comment: And what if I have Windows installed as well ? Won't the repartition create a problem ?

Comment: @Marine1 You can usually shrink/extend partitions without any problem. It is recommended that you backup. Refer some guides before doing so: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions